# <c:choose> not interpreted, all <c:when> and <c:otherwise> bodies are evaluated

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I wanna show state of a user when logged in the web site. i found out that its better use EL tags. but didnt work. please help me.

```
<c:choose> 

    <c:when test="${null}" >
        ${"Welcome Unknown User"}
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out> ${"Welcome dear"} ${SessionStateUser} </c:out>
    </c:otherwise>

</c:choose>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no typo in the first and last line? I would expect `<c:choose>`

Comment: I write this code in column of a table. the problem is representing all the word without pay attention to <when> tags

Comment: As @mthmulders says, one 'e' is missing in your keyword <c:choose> and </c:choose>

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it, but that was not reason!

Comment: I edited my codes.. what is my mistake? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the c:choose -> c:when block is constructed correctly. Also, why are the texts referenced as variables?

It should probably be more like this:

```
<c:choose> 
    <c:when test="${SessionStateUser == null}" >
       Welcome Unknown User
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       Welcome dear <c:out value="${SessionStateUser}"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I don't see a reason you would need this line: `var= "test" value = "${SessionStateUser}"` - in any case, naming a variable test is very confusing because the jsp test attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much..It helped me. I'm sorry for my mistakes. The reason is cause of my low knowledge. I'm new and amateur.